# Inserting data into mongodb using time comparison

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Suppose I have this code running on 3 different servers and every server is using a single database.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(userArray) {
    var report = mongoose.connection.db.collection('report');
    report.insert({datenow:new Date(),userlist:userArray},function(err,doc) {
      if(err) throw err;
    });
  }
},600000);
```

So, this piece of code is running every **10 minutes** on every server but I want only one of them to insert the data into the database. Since the data is same it is getting inserted **3 times**.

How do I check if the data is already inserted into the database by any one of the servers.

I tried making an incrementing `count` variable and insert it into the database and use it as a unique **ID** to check if it exists in the database. If it exists then I won't insert the data. But what if I have to restart the server for some reason, then the `count` will be reset to its initial value and this doesn't seem a viable solution.

So, how do I approach this problem? I am guessing I have to compare time somehow?

Comment: You could check for an updated_date field of your document, and validate that `updated_date > 10 minutes`, I guess.

Comment: How do I do that since data is inserted into the database consecutively and not concurrently so the date data doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to end up comparing timestamps and checking it anything is inserted in the last 10 minutes. This is the solution I came up with.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var currDate = new Date().getTime();
    if(keyPairNameArray) {

        var overallreport = mongoose.connection.db.collection('overallreport');
        overallreport.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, res){
            if(res.length > 0){
                var dbDate = new Date(res[0].datenow).getTime();
                var diffDate = currDate - dbDate;
                if(diffDate < 600000){

                } else {
                    overallreport.insert({datenow:new Date(),userlist:keyPairNameArray},function(err,doc) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                    });
                }
            } else {
                overallreport.insert({datenow:new Date(),userlist:keyPairNameArray},function(err,doc) {
                    if(err) throw err;
            });
            }
        });

    }
},610000);
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should use a **Cron expression instead of interval** and **use the execution time as primary key of your report** when you perform the insertion in the database.

**Explanation**

Cron expression can garantee that the execution of your script will occur at an accurate time. If you use this Cron expression : `00 */10 * * * *` (every 10 minutes), your script will execute at exactly `11:00:00`, `11:10:00`, `11:20:00`, so on.. for every server you have.

So you can use this execution time as key for your reports and it will prevent multiple insertion of the same report.

**Libs**

You can use this lib to use Cron with Node.js : [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)

**Example**

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know

Comment: Somehow my tech lead didn't like the idea of using cronjob. I had to find and I had to use time comparison. I am adding that as an answer. Thank you anyways.